# ruby rspec: how to make stub behave differently on each call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How to make stub in rspecs to behave differently on each call

for example,

```
teststub.onCall(0).stub(:testmethod).and_raise(Exception)
teststub.onCall(1).stub(:testmethod).and_return(true)
```

Seems like rspecs don't have `onCall` construct. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Using the before hook you can isolate them https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/hooks/before-and-after-hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the implementation of it. Then you can do whatever you want with it. Including but not limited to behaving differently on each call.

```
teststub.stub(:testmethod) do
  if @already_raised
    true
  else
    @already_raised = true
    raise Exception
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I haven't tried this. but, this seems like something would work.